# SSL Certification for GRPC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, grpc

Can you help me with ssl certification for gRPC server?

This is how i'm doing it with **C# Core Console application**:

```
const int Port = 50051;
const string host = "127.0.0.1";

var cacert = File.ReadAllText(@"Certs/ca.crt");
var servercert = File.ReadAllText(@"Certs/server.crt");
var serverkey = File.ReadAllText(@"Certs/server.key");
var keypair = new KeyCertificatePair(servercert, serverkey);
var sslCredentials = new SslServerCredentials(new List<KeyCertificatePair>() { keypair }, cacert, false);


var server = new Server()
{
    // setup host, port and server credentials
    Ports = { new ServerPort(host, Port, sslCredentials) },
    // register the service we built earlier
    Services = { Messages.BindService(new MessagesImpl()) }
};

server.Start();
```

I don't know how to provide SslServerCredentials in **ASP.NET core gRPC Server**?

cRPG server is started by adding in Stattup.cs file in section Configure:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddGrpc();
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        // Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a gRPC client.
        // To learn how to create a client, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086909
        endpoints.MapGrpcService<ServiceBaaseClass>();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should configure https when building the Host. That's in Program.cs, if you're using the grpc template.

Example:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
            {
                options.ListenLocalhost(50051, listenOptions =>
                {
                    listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2;
                    var cert = new X509Certificate2("localhost.pfx", "test");

                    listenOptions.UseHttps(cert);                    
                });
            });                   

            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

I have a pfx file generated this way:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout localhost.key -out localhost.cer -days 365 -subj /CN=localhost
openssl pkcs12 -export -out localhost.pfx -inkey localhost.key -in localhost.cer
```

Comment: Thanks. I have created new certificates and convert them into pfx file. gRPC server running without any errors. How now I can use those certificate files with client? Im new to certifications and .net core.

Comment: Are you're trying to do authentication with client certificates? Before I assumed you just wanted an encrypted connection to the grpc service.
If you're trying to authenticate with a certificate take a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-3.0
I'll edit my post to include this later today, but it shouldn't be hard to do from the documentation.

Comment: First I have created server using ca.crt, server.crt, server.key to ass sslServerCredentials then in client I'm using ca.crt, client.crt, client.key as sslCredentials this solution works in .NET Core Console App. But in ASP .Net Console Core App I need do that with ConfigureWebHostDefaults like you suggested. I have created pfx file using server.crt and server.key. Im building rpc services where most rpc will be servers but one with more complicated logic will be server/client as well using other rpc services. What do you recommending for this setup?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try as i did.
Firstly you should add this configuration to your appsettings.json

```
},
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Kestrel": {
    "EndpointDefaults": {
      "Protocols": "Http2"
    },
    "EndPoints": {
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://*:5002",
        "Certificate": {
          "Path": "c:\\test.pfx",
          "Password": "password1234"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "token": "DO6&gkOK5%$fRD#eRt$",
}
```

That certificate can be generated my many ways. IIS or powershell command. In this code is in drive c: just for testing.

Then you should get the token value like this on Program.main :

```
IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            // Duplicate here any configuration sources you use.
            configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("AppSettings.json");
            IConfiguration configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();

            string token = configuration["token"];
```

There are people that say that this token shouldn't be on configuration file but for now i don't know where else to put it. You should also investigate that. And tell me if you don't mind :)